# Trying to replicate a Polymer example on my server - it doesn't even initialize

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to replicate this example:
https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/tiles/index.html

Here's my version:
http://labs.recgr.com/polymer-dev/test1.html

As far as I am concerned, it's the same thing, and I am not getting any errors in Chrome Console, meaning all the paths are correct.

Why is it not working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your version both circles-page.html and the squares-page.html differ from the example version. Namely, the content between the `template` tags is missing. Thus you are loading empty pages and seeing nothing. Also, in the example you had to click on a circle to switch pages, but the circles have been removed, thus, you can't click on them. Try comparing these pages with the original versions.

Comment: That kind of error usually shows up if try to either register an element twice or the name was already taken.  I just had a quick look at your code and you seem to have copied the code for the squares-page into the circles-page.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Maria.